# Big number of tests run 3 hours. How to decrease the time?

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-automation

We've got a pretty big org, that has tens of millions of records and millions of apex code. The org has 1200 tests, that take 3 hours to run. 10 developers, that work in the org, all commit to 1 branch. Teamcity executes tests every time a developer adds a commit, but developer will see the results of tests only in 3 hours.

We cannot rewrite tests nor comment out some of them.

Was thinking about something like creating several(let's say, 10) dev orgs. Before running tests, parse the code for test classes, split all test classes by 10 and run each set of tests on those 10 dev orgs separately. And run all tests in 1 org nightly, to avoid unexpected issues.

Does anybody know about a tool that implements above? Or maybe there's another way?

Comment: If you are not willing to refactor your tests, you're not going to get very far. You should be able to convince management that the time invested will increase productivity correspondingly. I took a week or so once to do this in a large org, and it reduced our unit test time by 75%.

Comment: Hello @sfdcfox! We've tried, but no success there. That's why I'm thinking maybe there's another way. There should be though, since even tests're written perfectly, more tests's written, more time it takes to perform tests.

Comment: Your tests are running at about 9 seconds per test (3,600 seconds with 1,200 tests would be 9 seconds average). I am willing to bet that the average should be much lower for most of your tests, perhaps 2-3 seconds per test. You have a lot of room for optimization. There are tools you can use that use just part of the metadata (e.g. DX), but you can't automate it. You would still need to split your code into feature sets as separate directories or branches.

Comment: Also you might run not all tests but only the ones that cover classes that the deployed code might impact, and then in the evening run all tests so that you'll have the result in the morning. If tests are correctly selected and pass, there are chances that the complete set of tests passes too.

Comment: Run tests in parallel where possible on dev/test orgs. Run all tests more rarely on production